# I can't make SmartWizard Jquery 4 to work with Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm new to StackOverflow and I would like to ask if someone can help me fix my code. I can't make SmartWizard jquery 4 to work. I absolutely copied every line of code (except the sources of the css and js files) yet it still doesn't work. I'm sorry but I don't know what's wrong, I'm just a newbie in coding and I hope that you can help me understand this little problem.

I will attach my source code and images here.

Code from Jquery SmartWizard that I wish to copy is from http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard. Download the Zip file and open the index.html file under examples folder of the zip file.

Here is the output of the code I wish to copy:
[Output of the code I wish to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjdPg.png)

Here is my source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Smart Wizard - a JavaScript jQuery Step Wizard plugin</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <!-- Only difference is i'm using Bootstrap 4 -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"/>

  <link href="/sample2/resources/css/smart_wizard.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/sample2/resources/css/smart_wizard_theme_circles.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/sample2/resources/css/smart_wizard_theme_circles.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/sample2/resources/css/smart_wizard_theme_circles.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

 //the same as the code in index

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/sample2/resources/js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my project folder architecture: [project folder architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nROBb.png)

Here is the output of my code: [My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UXg2.png)

Once again I'm sorry I'm just a newbie in coding and thank you for replying to my question.

EDIT: I just found out that Jquery SmartWizard 4 is not compatible / does not work with Bootstrap 4 based on the comments but someone made it work with,as the commenter said, "It works after modifications. I still have small problems to solve. Thanks". Does anybody know how to make Jquery SmartWizard 4 work with Bootstrap 4? Thanks a lot!

EDIT2: I made it work with Bootstrap 4 now and here is what I did:

Changed this line of code:

From:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/sample2/resources/js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js"></script>`

- In this syntax it fetches this version of SmartWizard [Jquery SmartWizard 4.2.2 is being fetched.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcUh6.png)

To: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/sample2/resources//js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js"></script>`

- In this syntax it fetches the latest version of SmartWizard [Jquery SmartWizard 4.3.1 is being fetched.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvvCf.png)

Now my question is how come the extra slash made a difference on how the SmartWizard fetches its version, I would love to know why. Thanks a lot! But now I'm able to make Jquery SmartWizard 4.3.1 work with Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question editors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Jquery SmartWizard 4 work with Bootstrap 4, I had to change lines of code

From:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sample2/resources/js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sample2/resources//js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js"></script>
```

I did the same for the css files so it looks like this now

```
<link href="/sample2/resources//css/smart_wizard.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to use the minified version since when I used the minified version but the syntax of the link is "/sample2/resources/css/smart_wizard.min.css" the document fetches the SmartWizard v4.x version. I absolutely don't know why this happens ,where adding an extra slash after resources changes the version that is being used, so if anyone can provide answers to it that would be great! Thanks a lot! Cheers!